# Cannot load locally-built image into minikube

Tags: minikube, podman

I have built an image with podman:

```
$ podman build . -t test-karpenter-job:latest
STEP 1/6: FROM docker.io/library/python:latest
STEP 2/6: COPY src src
--> Using cache a7d56f0e9c4c788e2cd3d74eea060fe0b1b128c6244072986f6ff1cbae3d8adc
--> a7d56f0e9c4c
STEP 3/6: COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
--> Using cache 376dec0589e1e5afe07132eba0bdee935bbdcacc68029d75eadc660018d5a0ed
--> 376dec0589e1
STEP 4/6: COPY cli.py cli.py
--> Using cache 29ff6b20246b02d9942e7073a9b07ae136a3c16c6286be5735dc6b18fba7062e
--> 29ff6b20246b
STEP 5/6: RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
--> Using cache 3e6eee586b8c5b61ee56476c2a27e40017998915b5dc9d3b8b6dfdafdf368b45
--> 3e6eee586b8c
STEP 6/6: ENTRYPOINT ["python", "cli.py", "wait"]
--> Using cache 0c211c0880ee4808f9308c3c5eab0651e14d67797d1346a1593c4d1e8f4675bf
COMMIT test-karpenter-job:latest
--> 0c211c0880ee
Successfully tagged localhost/test-karpenter-job:latest
0c211c0880ee4808f9308c3c5eab0651e14d67797d1346a1593c4d1e8f4675bf
```

I then confirmed that it runs properly:

```
$ podman run test-karpenter-job:latest --seconds=3 --job_id=1
INFO:karpenter_test:JOB #001: waited 1 seconds...
INFO:karpenter_test:JOB #001: waited 2 seconds...
INFO:karpenter_test:JOB #001: waited 3 seconds...
INFO:karpenter_test:JOB #001: finished
```

I can see that the image is indeed present:

```
$ podman image ls
REPOSITORY                     TAG         IMAGE ID      CREATED         SIZE
localhost/test-karpenter-job   latest      0c211c0880ee  5 minutes ago   1.05 GB
```

But when I try to load it into minikube, it says that it does not exist:

```
$ minikube image load localhost/test-karpenter-job:latest
❗  The image 'localhost/test-karpenter-job:latest' was not found; unable to add it to cache.
```

What is the issue here?

Some other notes:

I am using rootless=True (I cannot get around this one so I hope this is not a showstopper)

My config:

```
- cpus: 4
- driver: podman
- memory: 6000
- rootless: true
- cache: map[]
- container-runtime: containerd
```

Answer (score 0):

A workaround I found was to save the image to a tar archive and load it instead:

```
podman save -o test-karpenter-job.tar localhost/test-karpenter-job:latest
minikube image load test-karpenter-job.tar
```